# Spring webflow dropdown list binding problem using @Modelattribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-webflow

**In my earlier project, I have bound dropdown to @ModelAttribute request to get the list of items and it worked. And tried the same technique in spring webflow but did not achieve the same result what I am doing wrong**

> Retrieve list from db or json file whatever

```
@ModelAttribute("messages")
public List<String> getListOfCountries(){

    return List.of("A", "B", "C", "D");
}
```

> And in thymeleaf file

```
 <option th:each="c: ${messages}" th:value="${c}" th:text="${c}">
 </option>
```

> Which worked in Spring MVC but not in spring webflow ? why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

```
<!--ASSIGNING MODELS-->
<var name="personalInfo" class="com.example.demo.alloystry.models.ApplicantPersonalInfoMain" />
<var name="employment" class="com.example.demo.alloystry.models.ApplicantEmployment" />
<var name="experience" class="com.example.demo.alloystry.models.ApplicantExperienceInfo" />
<var name="education" class="com.example.demo.alloystry.models.step4.Education" />
<var name="additional" class="com.example.demo.alloystry.models.additionalinfo.ApplicantAdditionalInfo" />



<!-- returning and adding inside flow registerModel instance -->
<on-start>
    <evaluate expression="applicantHandler.init()"
              result="flowScope.registerModel" />
</on-start>


<view-state id="personal" view="flows/register/personal-info" model="personalInfo">
    <transition on="billing" to="validatePersonal" />
    <on-exit>
        <evaluate expression="applicantHandler.addPersonalInfo(flowScope.registerModel, personalInfo)"></evaluate>
    </on-exit>
</view-state>


<action-state id="validatePersonal">
    <evaluate expression="applicantHandler.validatePersonalInfo(personalInfo, messageContext)" />
    <transition on="success" to="employment" />
    <transition on="failure" to="personal" />
</action-state>



<view-state id="employment" view="flows/register/employment" model="employment">
    <transition on="personal" to="personal" />
    <transition on="experience" to="experience" />
    <on-exit>
        <evaluate expression="applicantHandler.addEmploymentInfo(flowScope.registerModel, employment)"></evaluate>
    </on-exit>
</view-state>



<view-state id="experience" view="flows/register/experience" model="experience">
    <transition on="employment" to="employment" />
    <transition on="education" to="education" />
    <on-exit>
        <evaluate expression="applicantHandler.addExperienceInfo(flowScope.registerModel, experience)"></evaluate>
    </on-exit>
</view-state>



<view-state id="education" view="flows/register/education" model="education">
    <transition on="experience" to="experience" />
    <transition on="additional" to="additional" />
    <on-exit>
        <evaluate expression="applicantHandler.addEducationInfo(flowScope.registerModel, education)"></evaluate>
    </on-exit>
</view-state>



<view-state id="additional" view="flows/register/education" model="additional">
    <transition on="education" to="education" />
    <transition on="confirm" to="confirm" />
    <on-exit>
        <evaluate expression="applicantHandler.addAdditionalInfo(flowScope.registerModel, additional)"></evaluate>
    </on-exit>
</view-state>

<view-state id="confirm" view="flows/register/applicant-confirm" model="flowScope.registerModel">
    <transition on="submit" to="submit" />
</view-state>



<action-state id="submit">
    <evaluate expression="registerHandler.saveAll(flowScope.registerModel, messageContext)" />
    <transition on="success" to="success" />
    <transition on="failure" to="confirm" />
</action-state>



<!-- end state -->
<end-state id="success" view="flows/register/signup-success" />
<!--<end-state id="home" view="externalRedirect:contextRelative:/" />-->

<!--&lt;!&ndash; Global Transition &ndash;&gt;-->
<!--<global-transitions>-->
    <!--<transition on="home" to="home" validate="false" />-->
<!--</global-transitions>-->
```

**Thymeleaf personal info file**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head th:replace="fragments/head :: head(title='Personal Info')"></head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Personal Information (Stage 1)</h1>
            <hr/>
            <!--<a th:href="@{'~' + ${flowExecutionUrl} + '&_eventId_home'}" class="btn btn-danger">Home</a>-->

            <form method="post" th:object="${personalInfo}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">First Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input th:field="*{firstName}" type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname"
                               placeholder="First Name"/>
                        <small class="form-text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}"
                               th:errors="*{firstName}"></small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Last Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input th:field="*{lastName}" type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname"
                               placeholder="Last Name"/>
                        <small class="form-text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}"
                               th:errors="*{lastName}"></small>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="middlename" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Middle Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input th:field="*{middleName}" type="text" class="form-control" id="middlename"
                               placeholder="Middle Name"/>
                        <small class="form-text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('middleName')}"
                               th:errors="*{middleName}"></small>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="dob" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Date of Birth</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input th:field="*{dob}" type="text" value="10/24/1984" class="form-control" id="dob" required>
                        <small class="form-text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('dob')}"
                               th:errors="*{dob}"></small>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="dob" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Country</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="sizes" th:field="*{country}"
                                title="Choose country..." required>
                            <!--<option th:each="c: ${messages}"-->
                                    <!--th:value="${c}"-->
                                    <!--th:text="${c}">-->
                            <!--</option>-->

                            <option value="abs">Afghanistan</option>
                            <option value="abs">Irak</option>
                            <option value="abs">Syria</option>
                            <option value="abs">U got it right?</option>


                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input th:field="*{email}" type="text" class="form-control" id="email"
                               placeholder="example@gmail.com"/>
                        <small class="form-text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}"
                               th:errors="*{email}"></small>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="_eventId_employment">Next (Employment)
                            &raquo;
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script th:replace="fragments/scripts :: scripts"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please post your flow xml file also.

Comment: @joemokenela i did u can have a look and btw thanks for a quick response

Comment: *Which worked in Spring MVC but not in spring webflow*. In what way is it not working?

Comment: Spring webflow! I have declared this working ModelAttribute in my controller and bind it in my select field in my Thymeleaf file it was working in Spring Mvc but in spring webflow not @AlanHay